# How to expose internal data as readonly in a class?

Tags: c#, scope, access-modifiers

I have a class with an internal struct that contains data specific to that class.

However i want other classes to be able to read the data as a read-only setup.

So i tried:

```
public class MyClass{
    private Data _data;
    public Data Data
    {
        get { return _data; } //expose the internal data as read only
    }

    internal struct Data
    {
        public int SomeData;
    }
}
```

This gave me the error:

```
 Inconsistent accessibility: property type
```

It doesn't make much sense for the Data struct to be outside of `MyClass` since it's only related to that class. Everything else just reads it.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: no that `get { return _data; }` does not guarantee readonly, imo.. it just make sure the pointer on `Data` field is **readonly**. also, the reason why you get `inconsistent accessibility` is due to the fact that the `struct Data` is `internal` (assembly-wide) while the `Data` field is public. there is no way for the other assembly to understand what is `Data` struct is.

Comment: What would be the cleanest way to have Data restricted to `MyClass` but the data of it in `MyClass` readable to any class that has reference to `MyClass` then ?

Comment: In your actual scenario, does `Data` really have just one `int` field, or does it have lots of fields? Why is `Data` a struct and not a class?

Comment: It has about 15 i just simplified it for the question.I moved them all into a Data struct to make it cleaner but then needed to be able to read the values outside of the class so `internal` wasn't working. Didn't want to have Data exposed to other classes, since it gets messy and cluttered with things that i shouldn't be able to create.

Comment: actually @WDUK, [immutability is pretty hard to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2724848/4648586). on most cases you could simply use a class that only allow read for external assemblies e.g. `public int SomeData{ get { return  _someData; } internal set { _someData = value; }; }`. however that approach wont save you if you expose classes (e.g. `List`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a read only version of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724731/how-can-i-make-a-read-only-version-of-a-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your struct immutable and give that to the outside. Like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Data _data;
    public Data DataToExpose
    {
        get { return _data; } //expose the internal data as read only
    }

    public struct Data
    {
        public Data(int someData)
        {
            this.SomeData = someData;
        }
        public int SomeData { get; }
    }
}
```

Now people can use the `Data` from outside but it will be a read-only. Both the reference and the fields are read-only. It is good practice to make structs immutable anyways.